# How to make swiper.js react move 1 slide at a time?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

How can I make the slider move one slide at time when the left/right arrow buttons are clicked?

I can't see in the docs how to achieve this.

Example: show 5 slides, move 1 slide at a time.

```
            <Swiper
                modules={[Pagination, Navigation, A11y]}
                navigation
                onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
                onSwiper={swiper => console.log(swiper)}
                pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                breakpoints={{
                    768: {
                        width: 768,
                        slidesPerView: 1,
                    },
                    1200: {
                        width: 1200,
                        slidesPerView: 2,
                    },
                }}
            >
                {slides}
            </Swiper>
```

Comment: have you tried `slidesPerGroup` ?

Comment: yup it still moves 2 per click if I add slidesPerGroup : 1

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late answer for your problem, but maybe it will help others with the same problem.

I'm using `swiper/element` with `Angular v15`.

I tried to use `slidesPerView=1` and `slidesPerGroup=1` and it did not work.

What worked for me is `preventInteractionOnTranstition=true`.

My full swiper configuration is:

```
public config: SwiperOptions = {
    modules: [Navigation, Pagination, A11y, Mousewheel, Autoplay, EffectFade],
    autoHeight: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 4000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
      stopOnLastSlide: false,
    },
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeEffect: {
      crossFade: true,
    },
    injectStyles: [
      `
      .swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
        padding: 1rem;
        width: 3rem;
        height: 3rem;
        background-color: #00000022;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
        width: 1rem;
        height: 1rem;
        }

      `,
    ],
    speed: 1000,
    navigation: true,
    pagination: { clickable: true, dynamicBullets: true },
    centeredSlides: true,
    preventInteractionOnTransition: true,
  };
```